# Understanding the "Découpage de Lévy" (or Levy decomposition)

Tags: probability-theory

I am looking for someone to help me understand what exactly the "Découpage de Lévy" (or Levy decomposition) of random variables is and why it works. The book I am reading is "The Central Limit Theorem for real and banach valued random variables" by A. Araujo and E. Giné. In my opinion they are not doing a great job of explaining it. If anyone know a book that explains it in greater detail then I am very interested in hearing so!

First I am not even sure I understand what they mean by a "small variable" and "usually zero". Is is it small as in bounded by a certain value? And usually zero as in zero on a set of full measure? Also what is meant by means of randomization?

Then some notation is introduced as well as a lemma and proof which does at least make sense to me. They proceed to introduce $\eta$ to make the $V$-term and $U$-term independent. I assume this is so the sum is a convolution.

What I don't understand is the last part of page 52. It is written as if it follows from just looking at those previous results that normal approximates the $U$-term and Poisson the $V$-term. However that realisation is hard for the see. Is it instead meant to be a foreshadowing of Theorem 3.2 on the next page in which we see exactly that these terms are in fact well-approximated?

To make sure, is a random variable $X$ small in probability if $P(X>\delta)$ is small for an appropiate $\delta>0$?

Finally is there any *intuition* as to why it makes sense that sums of independent random variables are a convolution of normal and poisson?

I have attached the relevant to pages from their book.
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Where is the approximation? None of the expressions (or their RHS to be specific) in the theorems here are going to $0$ as $n \to \infty$. As a side comment, perhaps the authors had infinitely divisibility in mind when talking about sums of small iid random variables. This could be a generalization of Levy Ito decomposition.